# Want to know more about _?MatrixQ

Tags: matrix, expression-test

User, [@AndrzejKozlowski](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/182/andrzej-kozlowski) has uploaded a number of interesting demonstrations to the **Wolfram Demonstration Project**.

I have a particular interest these days in his [Pricing a Bermudan Option with the Longstaff-Schwartz Monte Carlo Method](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PricingABermudanOptionWithTheLongstaffSchwartzMonteCarloMeth/) and will likely submit a number of questions here as I try to understand what he does and the syntax he uses to do it.

In the notebook's **Initialization Code** section, the author has defined the following function:

```
step[stocks_?MatrixQ, {i_Integer, cashFlow_List}, k_, r_, times_] /; i >= 2 := 
  Module[
      {pos = Position[stocks[[All, -i]], x_ /; x < k], 
       X, Y, 
       cashflow = cashFlow, 
       newcashflow, f, z},
    X = Extract[stocks[[All, -i]], pos]; 
    Y = 
      With[{csh = Extract[#, pos] &/@ cashflow}, 
        Plus @@ MapThread[Times, {discounts[Length[csh] + 1, r, times], csh}]]; 
    f[i][z_] = Fit[Transpose[{X, Y}], {1, z, z^2}, z]; 
    newcashflow = 
      If[f[i][#] > Max[k - #, 0], 0, Max[k - #, 0]] & /@ stocks[[All, -i]]; 
    cashflow = ((1 - Unitize[newcashflow])*#) &/@ cashflow; 
    {i + 1, cashflow = Prepend[cashflow, newcashflow]}]
```

I've included the entire function in case it helps clarify or improve the context of my question.

I want to understand the function's use of `?MatrixQ` in the first argument and why the code would need it.

I just haven't come across this before now.

[image]

Does `?MatrixQ` insure that `stocks` is a matrix?
Any context or additional use cases of this syntax appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Try `f[mat_?MatrixQ]:=mat` and evaluate `f[1]` or `f[IdentityMatrix[3]]`.

Comment: Yes: just look at the "Applications" section of the Documentation Center page for `MatrixQ`. The more general use of `_?` is explained on the page `ref/PatternTest` (which I found by typing just `?` into the search bar of the Documentation Center).

Comment: Some possible uses: (1) It's a way to enforce one's own type-checking. (2) You can construct code like `step[myStocks,..]`, in which `step[]` will not be evaluated until you've assigned a matrix to `myStocks` in the same way that `Sin[x]` is not evaluated until `x` has a numeric value, say, in `Plot`.